# HttpServlet does not implement runnable or extend thread, why is it thread-able?

Tags: java, servlets, concurrency

For an object to be runnable, it needs to implement the `Runnable` interface or extend the `Thread` class, however, it does not seem that `HttpServlet` does any of these.

How come `HttpServlet` can be threaded or have i mistaken?

Comment: Just because something is "thread safe" (I am taking this as the meaing of "thread-able") doesn't mean it provides an entry-point for a thread.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106452/java-servlet-instantiation-and-session-variables

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Servlet itself is not a thread. The container maintains one instance of the servlet class and each request (thread) calls the same servlet object. So the servlet instances is shared across threads. In pseudo code it may look like this:

```
class ServerThread extends Thread {

    private javax.servlet.Servlet servlet;
    private javax.servlet.ServletRequest req;
    private javax.servlet.ServletResponse res;

    public ServerThread(javax.servlet.Servlet servlet, /* request and response */) {
        this.servlet = servlet;
        this.req = req;
        this.res = res;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        this.servlet.service(req, resp);
    }

}
```

No question, in reality it will be much, much, much more complex :-)

BTW: That's the reason your servlet classes have to be thread safe!

Comment: Also, are you saying that the Servlet is a singleton, or is it container-vendor independent?

Comment: @Chris Boon: I'm pretty sure it is a singleton, but I do not know how container providers (like Tomcat) handle that... they may have introduced some _crazy_ tricks. But yes, you should treat it as a singleton.

Answer (score 1):

Any class in Java may be executed on any thread, unless explicitly prohibited at run time by some sort of check. Without knowing the specifics of `HttpServlet`, I imagine that somewhere you encountered a statement to the effect of `HttpServlet` being thread-safe. If this is the case, that means a given instance of the class (or static methods of the class) can be safely used from any number of threads at once.

Also, the reason that `Thread` is a runnable is because it implements the `Runnable` interface; any class may do so. The notable aspect of `Thread`'s `run()` method is that when a `Thread` instance is started, its `run()` method is called on a separate thread.

Answer (score 0):

Anything is thread able. An EJB for spring beans are not threads themselves, but they run in multi threaded environments and hence they are thread able.