# Is servlet the singleton?

Tags: java, servlets

Reading some book that said the servlet is singleton from the container side. Is this true?

However even it is a singleton, we need to handle data synchronization etc

Comment: A servlet is not a singleton, but you should treat it as a singleton: synchronize or avoid instance level attributes. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6888268/httpservlet-does-not-implement-runnable-or-extend-thread-why-is-it-thread-able/6888301#6888301) as well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No. You can instantiate the same servlet class many times under different servlet names and URLs in the same web container and indeed in the same web-app.

Comment: If I have only one mapping rule for MyServlet in web.xml and not use @WebServlet annotation, can I be sure that there will always only one instance of MyServlet in container?

Comment: @JimJim2000 Not unless you also avoid the `SingleThreadModel`: see the other answer.

Answer (score 25):

Looking at the definition of the Singleton Pattern as defined in the [Cunningham & Cunningham, Inc. Wiki](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?SingletonPattern)

> Ensure a class has only one instance, and provide a global point of access to it.

I would say, no. From the perspective of the container one servlet object is accepted and managed including the creation of a [ServletContext](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html), but it does not prevent that there is not more than one instance of the servlet.

Regarding such issues I think it's best to look into the corresponding contract, which is in case of servlets defined in the [Java Servlet Specification](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315). They have addressed the number of instances of a servlet.

> **2.2 Number of Instances**
>
> The servlet declaration which is either via the annotation as
>   described in Chapter 8, “Annotations and pluggability” or part of the
>   deployment descriptor of the Web application containing the servlet,
>   as described in Chapter 14, “Deployment Descriptor”, controls how the
>   servlet container provides instances of the servlet. **For a servlet not
>   hosted in a distributed environment (the default), the servlet
>   container must use only one instance per servlet declaration. However,
>   for a servlet implementing the SingleThreadModel interface, the
>   servlet container may instantiate multiple instances to handle a heavy
>   request load and serialize requests to a particular instance.**
>
> In the case where a servlet was deployed as part of an application
>   marked in the deployment descriptor as distributable, a container may
>   have only one instance per servlet declaration per Java Virtual
>   Machine (JVM™). However, if the servlet in a distributable
>   application implements the SingleThreadModel interface, the container
>   may instantiate multiple instances of that servlet in each JVM of the
>   container.

It only specifies that the container must only use one instance (in the former case) and as *EJP* has pointed out in the *comment*:

> There is nothing in the Servlet Specification that prevents you from
>   re-instantiating the same servlet class under a different name in the
>   same web-app. Ergo, not a singleton.

**Reference** [Java Servlet Specification 3.0 MR](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=315) (p.6-7)

Comment: Well researched but not correct. There is nothing in the Servlet Specification that prevents you from re-instantiating the same servlet class under a different name in the same web-app. Ergo, not a singleton.

Comment: @EJP I agree with you. Taking a look at the singleton definition it is not ensured.

Answer (score 1):

Servlet can be initialized as a single instance or a pool of instances.

Here is an extract from <<Java Platform, Enterprise Edition The Java EE Tutorial Release 7>>:

A web container will typically create a thread to handle each request. To ensure that a
servlet instance handles only one request at a time, a servlet can implement the
SingleThreadModel interface. If a servlet implements this interface, no two threads
will execute concurrently in the servlet's service method. A web container can
implement this guarantee by synchronizing access to a single instance of the
servlet or by maintaining a pool of web component instances and dispatching each
new request to a free instance.

Answer (score -1):

No, Servlet is not a Singleton. It may create 2nd Object , depends on the incoming request and the Container behavior.

Comment: This doesn't add anything to the already-posted answers from almost 2 years ago.