# Multiple web service instance started when 2 web pages are open

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web, service, autowired

I am new Java web service programmer and I am looking to see why I see 2 instances of my service being created when I have 2 web pages open to it (One over localhost and another from a different PC using the server PC's IP address and web service URL).

Stack details: Using Tomcat, Java web service under Windows 7 PC.

I have a small web service that connects to a black box internally. Each time I bring up the web service and open up a URL associated with it, I can see the details from the black box. The problem is, when I have 2 web pages open to the web service (One over localhost and another from a different PC using the server PC's IP address and web service URL), I see two instances of the service being created and that are trying to connect to one black box at the same time. I need the ability to start the connect to the black box remotely or locally. But, only the localhost connection should win. I tried creating a servlet to start the service when Tomcat startup but not much luck with it. With the servlet, I see  my autowired Datasource connection is null.

Any idea on this would help.

@Repository
public class HServiceDAO  {

```
@Autowired
private DataSource mySql_dataSrc;
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>StartWebApp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.StartWebApp</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Did you create the service as a Singleton? Also be aware that servlets are not singleton per se: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11820840/is-servlet-the-singleton

Comment: Will try to create it as  singleton. As per this post, the service runs as a Singleton, is it? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11096310/singleton-object-in-java-web-service

Comment: Yes you can use a static variable, or let Spring do the work for you.

Comment: I am trying to have Spring do the work using @Autowired

Answer (score 0):

Created a singleton class for the service that started the connection to the black box. This eliminated the duplication connection to the black box.